# How and why would I write a class that extends null?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

JavaScript's [class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), added in ES6, apparently makes it legal to [extend `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends#Extending_null):

```
class foo extends null {}

new foo();
```

Some Googling reveals that it [was suggested on ES Discuss](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/extends-null) that such declarations be made an error; however, other commenters argued for them to be left legal on the basis that

> someone might want to create a class that has a `{__proto__: null}` prototype

and that side of the argument ultimately prevailed.

I can't make much sense of this hypothetical use case. For one thing, while the *declaration* of such a class is legal, it seems that *instantiating* a class declared in this way isn't. Trying to instantiate the class `foo` from above in Node.js or Chrome gives me the wonderfully daft error

> TypeError: function is not a function

while doing the same in Firefox gives me

> TypeError: function () {  
> } is not a constructor

It doesn't help to define a constructor on the class, as shown in MDN's current example of the feature; if I try to instantiate this class:

```
class bar extends null {
  constructor() {}
}

new bar();
```

then Chrome/Node tell me:

> ReferenceError: this is not defined

and Firefox tells me:

> ReferenceError: |this| used uninitialized in bar class constructor

What is all this madness? Why are these null-extending classes not instantiable? And given that they're not instantiable, why was the possibility of creating them deliberately left in the spec, and why did some MDN author think that it was [noteworthy enough to document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends$compare?locale=en-US&to=820971&from=805663)? What possible use case is there for this feature?

Comment: Have the `constructor` return `Object.create(null)` as a substitute. This apparently lets you avoid the automatic `super` call. https://jsfiddle.net/w7y2mbcd/ But then I guess it's not actually a member of that class.

Comment: Maybe have it return `Object.create(bar.prototype)`. https://jsfiddle.net/w7y2mbcd/1/

Comment: @squint nice - your second comment provides a way to actually instantiate a null-extending class, resulting in an object that doesn't have any of the methods from `Object.prototype`, like `.toString()` or `.isPrototypeOf()`. That's further than I got, although I'm still not quite sure why you'd want such an object.

Comment: I think sometimes people just want a clean object. This was more important before we had `Map`, so they'd use `Object.create(null)` to use as a generic map that can hold arbitrary properties that are not known in advance so that you can guarantee that any property lookup came from the interaction with the object instead of a default inheritance. Seems less important now, but then again there are probably some uses cases here and there. Don't know what they are though.

Comment: IMO, it would be better to not have to jump through hoops; the `super` call should just be avoided if there's no parent constructor. But then I haven't really thought it through either.

Comment: @squint you've referenced an implicit `super` call a couple of times in this comment thread, but not explained it in detail (perhaps assuming more detailed knowledge of ES6 classes from your audience than I personally have). Is that implicit call the cause of the errors trying to instantiate the `bar` from my question? Under what circumstances does this implicit call happen, and why?

Comment: I have limited familiarity with this syntax, but my understanding is that when you use the `class` syntax, the "parent" constructor is automatically invoke on the object or that if you try to reference `this`, you must first manually call `super()`... but I may have some details confused, so you'll be better off looking at other resources for a better explanation. But yes, I think that's probably the cause of the errors, though I could be very wrong about that.

Comment: FWIW, the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-class-definitions) says that `extends` can be followed by any *LeftHandSideExpression*, which basically means anything that could be put left of a `=`. That includes things like `foo()` and `null`. Now, neither `null = 42;` nor `foo() = 42` make sense, but they are valid and will throw a runtime error. OTOH, `class Foo extends bar() {}` makes sense. *edit:* Uh, `foo() = 42` and `null = 42` seem to be *early errors*, which are almost like syntax errors :-/

Comment: I have the same theory as Felix, it is allowed not because it is useful, but because it keeps the language uniform and "simple". By simple I mean, the docs read "any LeftHandSideExpression" instead of "any LeftHandSideExpression except null or etc."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**EDIT** (2021): TC39, which specifies JavaScript still hasn't resolved exactly how this is supposed to work. That needs to happen before browsers can consistently implement it. You can follow the latest efforts [here](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1321).

---

**Original answer**:

Instantiating such classes is meant to work; Chrome and Firefox just have bugs. [Here's](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5115) Chrome's, [here's](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1317391) Firefox's. It works fine in Safari (at least on master).

There used to be a [bug](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/543) in the spec which made them impossible to instantiate, but it's been fixed for a while. (There's [still](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/699) a related one, but that's not what you're seeing.)

The use case is roughly the same as that of `Object.create(null)`. Sometimes you want something which doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: So let's say I want to hook up every objects prototype BUT one I create with `extend null` or `Object.create(null)`?

Comment: It looks like the spec regarding `extends null` has [changed](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/commit/c57ef95c45a371f9c9485bb1c3881dbdc04524a2), and [Chrome isn't fixing this bug because of it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5115#c11).

Comment: Apparently this is still not fixed. What’s taking them so long?

Answer (score 15):

To answer the *second* part:

> I can't make much sense of this hypothetical use case.

That way, your object won't have `Object.prototype` in its prototype chain.

```
class Hash extends null {}
var o = {};
var hash = new Hash;
o["foo"] = 5;
hash["foo"] = 5;
// both are used as hash maps (or use `Map`).
hash["toString"]; // undefined
o["toString"]; // function
```

As we know, `undefined` in fact *is not* a function. In this case we can create objects without fearing a call on a field that shouldn't be there.

This is a common pattern through `Object.create(null)` and is common in a lot of code bases including big ones like Node.js .

(Note `new class Foo extends null {}` creates an object with an empty object as its prototype whereas `Object.create(null)` creates an object with `null` as its prototype)

Comment: `new class extends null {}` and `Object.create(null)` are not synonyms. The former (well, if we pretend it were actually working, anyway) has a prototype of its own (it just doesn’t derive from `Object.prototype`), the latter doesn’t.

Comment: @user3840170 yes you're right this answer predates "class reform" spec changes, I'll update it.

Comment: Wait actually where do I say in this answer they're the same?

Comment: In the last paragraph, ‘This is a common pattern through `Object.create(null)`’ implies they are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

It is in fact possible to construct a class that extends null, like follows:

```js
class bar extends null {
    constructor() {
        super() //required
    }
}

//super is not a function
//change the super class (for static methods only)
Object.setPrototypeOf(bar, class {});

let instance = new bar();
//instance checks still work
console.log(instance instanceof bar); // true
//instances still have a prototype that extends null
console.log(instance.toString); //undefined
```

Comment: It’s also possible to write `static { Object.setPrototypeOf(this, class {}); }` within the class body instead. This answer would also be better if you mentioned why the `Object.create` workaround doesn’t work so well.

Comment: You may want to `delete bar.prototype.constructor` if you want it to actually be an empty object

Answer (score 1):

### This answer doesn't answer "how can you make `class extends null`" work, but does explain how can you make a null-prototype class

You want your class prototype to have a `null` prototype, it's enough to set the prototype's prototype to `null`.

If you want your class to be *completely* empty (`instanceof` will still work), you may delete `prototype.constructor` as well.

```
class NullProtoRecord {
  static {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this.prototype, null);
    // @ts-ignore
    delete this.prototype.constructor;
  }
}
console.log(new NullProtoRecord());
// NullProtoRecord {}
console.log('is NullProtoRecord:', new NullProtoRecord() instanceof NullProtoRecord);
// is NullProtoRecord: true 
console.log('is Object:', new NullProtoRecord() instanceof Object);
// is Object: false 
console.log('all keys:', allKeys(new NullProtoRecord()));
// all keys: [] 

function allKeys(o) {
  if (!o) return [];
  return [...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o), ...allKeys(Object.getPrototypeOf(o))];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A class that `extends null` is a perfectly ordinary class with its own instance prototype, where it can define instance methods and accessors.  It just happens not to inherit from `Object.prototype`.  As for why you would want to have such a thing in the first place, I can think of two benefits:

- to withhold primitive conversions like `toString`, `valueOf`, and implicit conversions (those will throw `TypeError`)
- to detect bugs such as code doing `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` instead of `Object.hasOwn(obj, key)`, or `obj instanceof Object` instead of `typeof obj === 'function' || typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null`, etc.

It’s rather silly to treat an `extends null` class as a key-value mapping.  For that, an ordinary `Object.create(null)` should suffice (it does not have an extraneous prototype), if for whatever reason you cannot just use a `Map`.

---

Using `null` in the `extends` clause was *meant* to work, and this is evident from reading the original ECMAScript 6 specification, where there is a specific carve-out that allows `extends null` classes to be declared ([ECMA-262 6th Ed. §14.5.4](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation), steps 6.e–f), where it would otherwise have been a `TypeError`.  That such classes cannot be normally *constructed* was an oversight on the part of the committee.  The reason is rather subtle and tedious, and has to do with the details of how inheritance works in ECMAScript.

ECMAScript divides classes into two kinds: “base” (those declared without an `extends` clause) and “derived” (those declared *with* one).  “Derived” classes must invoke the superclass constructor in their own constructor, either by using `super(...)` or implicitly, when the constructor declaration is omitted; “base” classes have no superclass constructor to invoke and *must not* perform a `super(...)` call.

Now, inheritance works along two lanes:

- On one lane, the instance prototype of the subclass (the object held in its `.prototype` property) has as its own prototype the instance prototype of the superclass.  This ensures that:

  - Subclass instances inherit instance methods from the superclass, and
  - Subclass instances are considered instances of the superclass (in the sense of the `instanceof` operator).

  “Base” classes have `Object.prototype` as their instance prototype prototype (and their instances are therefore `instanceof Object`).
- On the other lane, the subclass object *itself* has the superclass object as its prototype.  This ensures that:

  - Static methods of the superclass are inherited by the subclass, and
  - The subclass is able to locate and invoke the superclass constructor.

  The invocation of the superclass constructor only happens for “derived” classes (those with an `extends` clause).  Classes without an `extends` clause skip the superclass constructor call, and have `Function.prototype` (which is not a constructor) as their prototype, like normal functions.

The above prose may have been hard to follow; it’s probably much clearer on a diagram.  A series of declarations like this:

```js
class Base {}
class Derived extends Base {}
class Further extends Derived {}
```

results in an object graph illustrated below:

```text
LEGEND:
═══▶  [[Prototype]] slot
───→  .prototype property
╌╌╌→  constructor for                             null
                                                   ▲
     ╭──────────────────────╮          ╭───────────╨────────╮
     │  Function.prototype  ╞══════════▶  Object.prototype  │
     ╰────▲─────────────────╯          ╰───────────▲────────╯
          ║                                        ║
     ╭────╨───╮                          ╭─────────╨────────╮
     │  Base  ├──────────────────────────→  Base.prototype  │
     ╰────▲─┬─╯                          ╰──▲──────▲────────╯
          ║ ┆                 ╭─────────────╨───╮  ║
          ║ ╰╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌→  new Base(...)  │  ║
  super() ║                   ╰─────────────────╯  ║
     ╭────╨───────────╮               ╭────────────╨────────╮
     │    Derived     ├───────────────→  Derived.prototype  │
     │  extends Base  │               ╰─────▲──────▲────────╯
     ╰────▲─┬─────────╯    ╭────────────────╨───╮  ║
          ║ ╰╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌→  new Derived(...)  │  ║
  super() ║                ╰────────────────────╯  ║
     ╭────╨──────────────╮            ╭────────────╨────────╮
     │      Further      ├────────────→  Further.prototype  │
     │  extends Derived  │            ╰─────▲───────────────╯
     ╰──────┬────────────╯ ╭────────────────╨───╮
            ╰╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌→  new Further(...)  │
                           ╰────────────────────╯
```

The `extends null` case is handled specially, but… not specially enough.  The prototype of the instance prototype is made `null`, and the prototype of the class is `Function.prototype`, but the class is still treated as a “derived” class that should invoke its superclass constructor… which is not a constructor at all.  And *this* is what causes problems.

```text
                                                         null
                                                         ▲  ▲
         ╭──────────────────────╮    ╭───────────────────╨╮ ║
  ╭╌╌╌╌╌╌┤  Function.prototype  ╞════▶  Object.prototype  │ ║
  ┆      ╰────▲─────────────────╯    ╰────────────────────╯ ║
  ┆           ║                                             ║
  ┆           ║                                             ║
  ┆   super() ║                                             ║
  ┆      ╭────╨───────────╮                  ╭──────────────╨──╮
  ┆      │      Foo       ├──────────────────→  Foo.prototype  │
  ┆      │  extends null  │                  ╰─────────────────╯
  ┆      ╰───────┬────────╯  
  ┆              ╰╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌→  TypeError because
  ╰╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌→ Function.prototype
                                 is not a constructor
```

But knowing how the error happens also allows us to create a workaround.  We actually have a choice of two, either requiring a call to `Object.setPrototypeOf`:

- use the `extends null` clause, and transplant a dummy class as a prototype of the constructor;

  ```js
  class Foo extends null {
    static {
      Object.setPrototypeOf(this, class {});
    }
  }
  ```

  ```text
  LEGEND:
  ╌╌╌▷  prototype before Object.setPrototypeOf         null
                                                       ▲  ▲
       ╭──────────────────────╮    ╭───────────────────╨╮ ║
       │  Function.prototype  ╞════▶  Object.prototype  │ ║
       ╰─────────────▲────────╯    ╰────────────────────╯ ║
            △        ║                                    ║
            ╎  ╭─────╨──────╮                             ║
            ╎  │  class {}  ├──→ [irrelevant]             ║
            ╎  ╰─────▲──────╯                             ║
            ╔════════╝                                    ║
    super() ║                                             ║
       ╭────╨───────────╮                  ╭──────────────╨──╮
       │      Foo       ├──────────────────→  Foo.prototype  │
       │  extends null  │                  ╰──▲──────────────╯
       ╰──────┬─────────╯        ╭────────────╨───╮
              ╰╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌→  new Foo(...)  │
                                 ╰────────────────╯
  ```
- omit the `extends` clause entirely, and transplant away `Object.prototype` as the prototype of the instance prototype.

  ```js
  class Bar {
    static {
      Object.setPrototypeOf(this.prototype, null);
    }
  }
  ```

  ```text
                                                       null
                                                       ▲  ▲
       ╭──────────────────────╮    ╭───────────────────╨╮ ║
       │  Function.prototype  ╞════▶  Object.prototype  │ ║
       ╰───▲──────────────────╯    ╰────────────────────╯ ║
           ║                                           △  ║
           ║                                           ╎  ║
           ║                                           ╔══╝
       ╭───╨───╮                           ╭───────────╨─────╮
       │  Bar  ├───────────────────────────→  Foo.prototype  │
       ╰───┬───╯                           ╰──▲──────────────╯
           ┆                     ╭────────────╨───╮
           ╰╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌→  new Foo(...)  │
                                 ╰────────────────╯
  ```

You can see how either works below:

```js
class Bad extends null {}

// separately declared for demonstrative purposes
class Null {}

// transplant a dummy constructor prototype
class Good extends null {
  static {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Null);
  }
}

// transplant away instance prototype’s prototype
class AlsoGood {
  static {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this.prototype, null);
  }
}

console.log(new Good() instanceof Object);         // false
console.log(new Good() instanceof Null);           // false
console.log(new Good() instanceof Good);           // true

console.log(new AlsoGood() instanceof Object);     // false
console.log(new AlsoGood() instanceof AlsoGood);   // true

console.log(new Bad());                            // throws TypeError
```

`static` blocks are a new feature in ES2022 (ECMA-262 13th Ed.); if you are targetting older versions of JS, you can replace it with `Object.setPrototypeOf(Good, class {});` (or `Object.setPrototypeOf(AlsoGood.prototype, null);`) outside the class body.

You may be tempted to use a return override in a constructor, as some answers suggest, instead of transplanting prototypes after construction.  This is unfortunately incompatible with instance fields, both public and private:

```js
class Bad extends null {
  constructor() {
    return Object.create(new.target.prototype);
  }

  #value = 42;
  token = 69;

  get() {
    return this.#value;
  }
}

class Good extends null {
  static {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, class {});
  }

  #value = 42;
  token = 69;

  get() {
    return this.#value;
  }
}

console.log(new Good().token);   // 69
console.log(new Good().get());   // 42
console.log(new Bad().token);    // undefined
console.log(new Bad().get());    // throws TypeError
```

If you define an explicit constructor for your class that `extends null`, you will have to invoke `super()` in it, just like with every other class declared with an `extends` clause.  This does not apply if you decide to transplant away the instance prototype prototype instead.

```js
class Wrapper extends null {
  static {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, class {});
  }

  #value;

  constructor(value) {
    super();
    this.#value = value;
  }

  get() {
    return this.#value;
  }
}

class WrapperAlt {
  static {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this.prototype, null);
  }

  #value;

  constructor(value) {
    // no extends, no super()
    this.#value = value;
  }

  get() {
    return this.#value;
  }
}
```