# why static methods of Object class are not inherited by other classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, static

In JavaScript If I create a class with a static method and then create a subclass of that class, I can call the static method using subclass name too (static methods are inherited).

Object class which is superclass of all classes has many static methods.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object
But why none of those methods can be called using any of subclass names ?

update:
I noticed some suggested to explicitly '*extend*' **Object**.
But Object class is already superclass of every class in JavaScript. the proof is the **.toString()** method that every object from every class has it and we know it is inherited from Object class even if you don't explicitly write 'extends Object'.
So every class is implicitly extending Object (directly or through inheritance chain) but why non-static methods are being inherited automatically and not the static methods?

as for sample code:

```
class Test {
  constructor() {}
}

const test = new Test();
console.log(test.toString()); // works, inherited from Object class
console.log(Test.<any static method of Object>)); // doesn't work
```

Comment: Why do you say they can't be? https://jsbin.com/lolujigoxu/edit?js,output

Comment: Could you elaborate your question by providing a simple code example?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Try `String.entries` or `Math.entries`, for example. I guess that's what the question is about. If the answer is "they don't inherit from `Object`" then the next question would probably be why `"myString".hasOwnProperty` _does_ work then and why `"hi" instanceof Object` is true! (This made me actually think about how static properties are inherited with the `class` keyword, from a prototype perspective.)

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is somewhere in here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14162038/476

Comment: @deceze I don't think that's related, not any more than say [How and why would I write a class that extends null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41189190/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a deliberate decision back in 2012 when ES6 was worked on - you can find it in [the meeting notes on *Maxmin class semantics*](https://github.com/tc39/notes/blob/main/meetings/2012-07/july-26.md#maxmin-class-semantics):

> *Mark S. Miller*: so `Foo` will inherit `Object.create`, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, etc?
>
> *Dave Herman*: that does mean we'll be more and more hampered from adding methods to Object
>
> […]
>
> *Mark S. Miller*: polluting of statics with everything in `Object` is fatal; those are just not relevant to most of the class abstractions
> people write; when I write `class Point { }` I don't want
> `Point.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`
>
> *Allen Wirfs-Brock*: you only opt into that with `class Point extends Object`; with `class Point { }` you don't get any of that stuff
>
> […]
>
> *Yehuda Katz*: also, there are override hazards of pollution: if someone freezes `Object`, then you wouldn't be able to override sweet class method names like `keys()`, so the ability to avoid that pollution is important

I'm glad they've chosen this behaviour. Notice that not doing any inheritance of class (constructor function) objects - common in ES5 - was also on the table, it would have meant that calling static methods with dynamic `this` on subclasses would have been quite awkward. (Notice that at the time, there was no `static` modifier for method definitions, static methods were created by simple `Foo.method = function() { … };` assignments).

The "static methods" of `Object` were never (and still are not) meant to be dynamic, they neither do use the receiver (`this`) nor are they expected to be called on "subclasses". `Object` really is just a namespace for the most basic tools (intrinsic functions) for working with objects. When calling `Test.create()`, one would expect that to create a new test, not require a prototype object as an argument.

Another reason why this would be weird is that when a class inherits from another class, including `Object`, its `constructor` must call `super()`. Simple classes that don't mean to use any inheritance shouldn't have to deal with that. So the case where a `class` has no `extends` clause is already handled differently, with a focus on usability since it's the most common use. Not making those class objects inherit from `Object` is just another feature.

Finally, it follows the precedent of other built-in "classes". `Function.prototype`, `Array.prototype`, `Error.prototype` etc all inherit from `Object.prototype`, but their constructors do not inherit from `Object`.

This is also corroborated by early tutorial blog posts such as [this one](https://2ality.com/2012/07/esnext-classes.html):

> [When you] don’t extend: `class Foo {}`
>
> - The prototype of `Foo` is `Function.prototype` (as for all functions).
> - The prototype of `Foo.prototype` is `Object.prototype`.
>
> That is the same as for functions. Note that the above is not equivalent to `class Foo extends Object`, for the only reason that you normally want to avoid `Foo` inheriting methods such as `Object.create()`.

Comment: Cool reference. thanks. If they ever make a movie or TV series from those transcripts I'll watch it :)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that originally JavaScript didn't have classes. When the concept was introduced, it was basically implemented as syntax sugar over constructor functions, which are instances of `Function`.

When resolving *static* properties and methods, what matters is the prototype of the constructor function itself (not the prototype of *instances* created from that constructor). For a class defined without `extend`ing another class, the prototype of the constructor function is `Function.prototype`, not `Object.prototype`.

```js
class A {}
class B extends Object {}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(A) === Function.prototype); // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(A) === Object); // false
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(B) === Object); // true
```

`Function.prototype` doesn't have properties like `keys` or `entries`, but it does have properties like `apply`, `call`, and `bind`, which is why you can call these functions on any function. So in your example, `Test.apply` does have a value.

If `Test.entries` were to inherit from `Object.entries`, then `Function.entries` would do the same, which I think would be counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked why Test should be extended with Object in order static methods to work.
Well, JS classes is a ES6 feature. Before that only prototypes exist.
JS classes require explicit extending from a base class.
When you omit this, the class' instances

**are extended from Object with Object.prototype**

so no static methods.

```js
class Test extends Object{

}

console.log(Test.values({key:'value'}));

// no base class
class Test2{
    test = 'test'
}

// check that Object.prototype is used
console.log(new Test2 instanceof Object);
console.log(new Test2().hasOwnProperty('test'));

// but sorry, no static methods   
console.log(Test2.values({key:'value'}));
```

Comment: But why do I have to explicitly write "extends Object".
Object is already superclass of every class in JS that is whey every object of every class has "toString" method.

Comment: @pref added an example `new Test2().hasOwnProperty('test')` which shows that without `extends` the `Object.prototype` is used still

Comment: it's weird, but thanks.